# missing rows with empty value in hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables with foreign key references:

```
Comm TABLE:

+----+------------+
| ID |    NAME    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | comm name1 |
|  2 | comm name2 |
|  3 | comm name3 |
+----+------------+

LOCATION TABLE: - COMM_ID FK to  Comm --> id

+---------+------+-----+
| COMM_ID | FORM | TO  |
+---------+------+-----+
|       1 | 720  | 721 |
|       1 | 725  |     |
|       1 |      | 766 |
|       1 |      |     |
|       2 | 766  | 225 |
|       3 | 766  | 222 |
+---------+------+-----+
```

The problem is Hibernate returns my comm object
with missing `location` in `SET<location>` 
All rows where there is no `FROM` **and** `TO` (like the last row with COMM_ID = 1 in table LOCATION) are missing.

Otherwise (if only one of `FROM` or `TO`) the row is returned...
why?

`Comm` objects:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="LOCATION",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="COMM_ID"))
 public Set<LOCATION> getLocations(){
    return locations;
 }
 public void setLocations(Set<LOCATION> locations){
    this.locations=locations;
 }
```

`Location` class:

```
@Embeddable
class Location implements java.io.Serializable {

    private BigDecimal fromLocationId;
    private BigDecimal toLocationId;

    public Location() {
    }

    public Location(BigDecimal fromLocationId, BigDecimal toLocationId) {
        this.fromLocationId = fromLocationId;
        this.toLocationId = toLocationId;
    }

    @Column(name="FROM", nullable=true, precision=22, scale=0)
    public BigDecimal getFromLocationId() {
        return this.fromLocationId;
    }

    public void setFromLocationId(BigDecimal fromLocationId) {
        this.fromLocationId = fromLocationId;
    }

    @Column(name="TO", nullable=true, precision=22, scale=0)
    public BigDecimal getToLocationId() {
        return this.toLocationId;
    }

    public void setToLocationId(BigDecimal toLocationId) {
        this.toLocationId = toLocationId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return com.google.common.base.Objects.hashCode(fromLocationId, toLocationId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final LOCATION  other = (LOCATION) obj;
        return com.google.common.base.Objects.equal(this.fromLocationId, other.fromLocationId) && com.google.common.base.Objects.equal(this.toLocationId, other.toLocationId);
    }
}
```

I'm using Hibernate - 4.3.6

**LOG:**

```
org.hibernate.SQL - 
    select
        locations0_.COMM_ID as COMM_ID1_2_0_,
        locations0_.FROM as FROM2_8_0_,
        locations0_.TO as TO4_8_0_
    from
        LOCATION  locations0_ 
    where
        locations0_.COMM_ID=1
```

I checked it in my DB and it's return the correct result.

Comment: Am I missing something? your data show from and to to be Strings, but you mapping says they should be numbers????

Comment: Please post the whole `LOCATION` class. Since you're using `Set` it is mandatory that you override the `equals` and `hashCode` method correctly.

Comment: `public boolean equals(com.google.common.base.Object obj)` This doesn't look right. Please post the _full_ class. And check if you post the real code.

Comment: Two things: first why is the "comm_id" variable missing? Don't you need it? It can be problematic if two rows of that table have different "comm_id"s, but both have no "from" or "to", so they are still "logical" equal to your program. Second: I assume that `com.google.common.base.Objects.equal(this.fromLocationId, other.fromLocationId)` is dangerous here. Since it should call `BigDecimal#equals` and this implementation is very restrictive about "equal" instances. To check if this is the problem, please test [this implementation](http://pastebin.com/u75TY56b) or use `List` instead of `Set`

Comment: I change my "equal" method and it's didnt help, anyway i add breakpoint to "equal" method and not hit was happend. (when location returns it's hit this breakpoint)

Comment: forgot to mention Location is "@Embeddable" Comm is @Entity

Comment: Are you aware that they might be duplicates in your Location table.

Comment: yes im aware of that and it's ok.

Comment: In that case you need to use a `List` instead of a `Set`.

Answer (score 3):

An embeddable object's data is contained in several columns in its parent's table. Since there is no single field value, there is no way to know if a parent's reference to the embeddable is null. One could assume that if every field value of the embeddable is null, then the reference should be null, but then there is no way to represent an embeddable with all null values. JPA does not allow embeddables to be null, but some JPA providers may support this.

Hibernate : When loading an entity, embedded references are set to null if all of the columns in the embeddable are null.

for more info [click here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables)

so when u saving nullable embeddable values then hibernate allow to save but at the time of fetching hibernate discard those rows which are nullable.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is nothing wrong with the output. I think you just confused between `embeddable` and `entity`. because, as far as i know. You only use the `embeddable` class only for to make a development of an entity much easier if there are lot of entity which using the same fields.

And from what I see, the `hashcode` and `equals` methods do treat all those six records as a different record. So, I think what you want is to make the `Location` class into something like this.

```
@Entity
class Location implements java.io.Serializable {

private Long commId;
private BigDecimal fromLocationId;
private BigDecimal toLocationId;

// all the setter getter here

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return com.google.common.base.Objects.hashCode(commId);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final LOCATION  other = (LOCATION) obj;
    return com.google.common.base.Objects.equal(this.commId, other.commId);
}
}
```

or, of course you can make the get method to return a `List` and then remove a row if the row is missing `from` or `to` value.